# Table doesn't replace inside conditionals (If, Which)

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, hold, conditional

This:

```
Table[If[cond, y], {y, 1, 3}]
```

outputs this:

```
{If[cond, y], If[cond, y], If[cond, y]}
```

The `y` is not replaced by its value, as is normally the case with `Table[]`. This also happens with `Which[]`.

How do I get Table to actually replace the values for y?
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

While investigating to document the question i found the solution:

**Why?**

Because: *"Values of Table variables do not get substituted inside held expressions"* and `If` has the Attribute `HoldRest` and `Which` has `HoldAll`:

```
In[1]:= Attributes[Which]
        Attributes[If]

Out[1]= {HoldAll, Protected}

Out[2]= {HoldRest, Protected}
```

**How to "fix" it?**

Using `With`:

```
Table[With[{y = y}, If[cond, y]], {y, 1, 3}]
```

This behavior is further illustrated by this example from the "Possible issues" section from the `Table` documentation:

> Values of Table variables do not get substituted inside held expressions:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= Table[Hold[i], {i, 5}]
>
> Out[1]= {Hold[i], Hold[i], Hold[i], Hold[i], Hold[i]}
> ```
>
> Use With to insert values:
>
> ```
> In[2]:= Table[With[{i = i}, Hold[i]], {i, 5}]
>
> Out[2]= {Hold[1], Hold[2], Hold[3], Hold[4], Hold[5]}
> ```

Comment: It's strange that there are no documented cases of this happening(in forums or stackexchange) , since both `If` and `Table`are commonly used functions, and most basic users don't know about the existence of the `Hold` attributes. I myself discovered this by error, never even imagined that if had a `HoldRest`.

Comment: Please see the duplicate link above. This is a documented and expected behaviour of `If`. The answer in  the link also goes in to some discussion on why `If` _must_ have this attribute. It is true that basic users won't know about the hold attributes, but I suppose that's part of learning a language... at some point you'll hit a "strange behaviour" which teaches you something new :)