# Table and evaluation order

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, scoping

I thought Table should not evaluate the inner code until it inserts the value. I'm confused by

```
test1[3]="a";
test2[4]="b";
Table[DownValues[i],{i,{test1,test2}}]
```

which outputs `{{}, {}}` where I would have expected it to match

```
{DownValues[test1],DownValues[test2]}
```

Compare also with for instance:

```
test[i]="error";
Table[test[i],{i,{1,2,c}}]
```

where clearly it does not evaluate test[i] before insertion of the table values. What is going on here?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. Try `Table[DownValues[Evaluate@i], {i, {test1, test2}}]` instead.

Comment: @MarcoB, so why is the Evaluate necessary?

Comment: see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41418/27539. I would say the answer is in the first sentence: *Because: "Values of Table variables do not get substituted inside held expressions"* (I am not sure why this is the case though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table does not replace the iteration variable (in the style of Replace) which would "pass" through the `Hold`. Instead it uses `Block`, which apparently assigns an OwnValue to the iteration variable. See,

```
Table[OwnValues[i],{i,3}]
```

which outputs `{{HoldPattern[i] :> 1}, {HoldPattern[i] :> 2}, {HoldPattern[i] :> 3}}`. This `OwnValue` is held by `DownValues` due to its `HoldAll` attribute. Thus, we evaluate `DownValues[i]`. Instead of `DownValues[test1]` (and `DownValues[test2]`).

---

The solution is to use `Table[With[{i=i},...]` as is discussed in [Table doesn't replace inside conditionals (If, Which)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41417/table-doesnt-replace-inside-conditionals-if-which/41418#41418)

(This also possibly makes this a  duplicate by the way. The answers on the other post however do not explain that it Table uses OwnValues which here end up being held.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `Attributes` alloted to `Downvalues` are `HoldAll` and `Protected`. This is in addition to the `HoldAll` attribute of `Table`.

Hence, in the first case, first, `Downvalues` returns an empty list, which Table takes in to create its own list. So, you get a list of two empty lists.

In the second case, you don't have such an intermediary function which has a `HoldAll` attribute to begin with.

**Edit 1**:

```
Table[DownValues[i], {i, {test1, test2}}] // Trace
```

This clearly shows, that `Downlnvalues[i]` never gets substituted by `Downvalues[test1]` or `Downvalues[test2]`.

Hope this clears things out

Comment: That does not address the whole story. Otherwise I would expect: `Table` has `HoldAll` and so all evaluation is halted. Than `Table` does its thing replaces `i` and then we have `DownValues[test1]`. At this point `DownValues` has `HoldAll`, but that is what we want.  Instead table does not replace `i` with `test1`. Does it instead assigns `i` a value (DownValue? apparently not or we would see that instead as output), this value is then held because of `DownValues`'s `HoldAll` attribute, and we get the wrong result. Something like that?

Comment: Ah indeed it seems it stores an `OwnValue` for `i`.

Comment: but this doesn't explain *why* `Table` doesn't substitute the arguments of held expressions, does it?